# How string comparison happens in dotnet?

Tags: c#, string

I have say

```
var str1 = "Name1"; 
var str2 = "Name1";
```

if I do `str1 == str2` the output will be true(as expected).

But my question is how it does the comparison..is it character by charecter or how?

Then how string.Intern helps here in improving the performance?

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to know this? The reason you are looking for this information may help provide you with a better answer.

Comment: for my sake of knowledge and after going thru this http://www.worldlingo.com/ma/enwiki/en/String_intern_pool

Comment: @generaluser: the link is not working right anymore, it is actually pointing to a medical website.

Answer (score 7):

For strings the `==` compares the values of the strings ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)). However, in this case the references will be the same due to string interning as all literal strings are interned by default. If you look at the implementation for `==` you'll see that it calls `string.Equals`, which does a reference comparison first.

Comment: Behavior of '==' operator with strings: [New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx#stringsinnet20_topic6)

Comment: Good to know, I always used `String.CompareTo(string)`. Java instead, by using `==` it only checks whether the reference is equal.
How can I have a look into the implementations? Reflector doesn't properly disassemble `String.Compare(string` :(

Answer (score 1):

String equality will first check if the strings to be compared are the same object. In this case because of string interning that will be true, comparison will immeadiatly return instead of any sort of character comparison.

String interning can be manipulated in code but it is more often somethng that is carried out as part of compilation. All string literals are compiled into a table and references to the string literals are replaced with references to entries in these tables. This helps to pool strings and so may reduce memory. A side effect is that string literals with the same value will now have the same reference so comparison will be extremely efficient.

Although the interning process is most familiar as part of compilation, strings can be interned programatically.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
string x = "hello";
string y  = "world";
bool result = x == y;
```

you're calling String::op_Equality which in turns calls the *static* String.Equals method, which looks like this:

```
if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
    return true; 
}
if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) { 
    return false;
} 
return EqualsHelper(a, b);
```

The EqualsHelper method compares character by character.

Which means it first checks if the references are equal.

Answer (score 0):

First it checks for object reference to be same (reson explained by other answers), if not then it goes with char by char comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if the strings reference the same object (as is the case in your example) then the comparison can return `true` immediately. Secondly, if the strings are not of the same length, then the comparison can return `false` immediately. After that, it is indeed a character-by-character comparison.

This is based on the output from Reflector, looking at .NET 4.0.